# PyQt5 pyuic module error

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm tryng to convert some .ui file into .py. 
I looked all over the internet for some tutorials and none seem to work for me, pyuic.bat is not found anywere un mi pc, and if i run

```
python pyuic.py -o file.py file.ui
```

i always get some errors like:

```
file "pyuic.py", line 28, in module
    from .diver import Diver
Valuerror: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

i'm using python 2.7 on windows 10, and PyQt 5.6.

Comment: This might not be the solution but in general I would suggest using Python 3.6 or at least 3.5, because version 2.7 is soon 7 years old.

Comment: I already have most of the program i want to make... i just need a gui. 
And the code i have is in 2.7

Comment: Add the folder containing the `pyuic5` batch file to your `%PATH%`, and then run `pyuic5 -o file.py file.ui`. The batch file should be installed to a location like "C:\Program Files\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyuic5.bat".

Comment: i can't find `pyuic5` anywere..

Answer (score 2):

You might not have the `pyuic5.bat` file depending on how you installed PyQt5. But you can make one easily enough. Just create a file named `pyuic5.bat` and place it in your `PyQt5` directory e.g. `C:\python-qt5\PyQt5`), and have the file contain:

```
python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic %*
```

This requires that:

- Your `PyQt5` directory is listed in your `PYTHONPATH`, e.g. `C:\python-qt5`,
- The directory containing `pyuic5.bat` is listed in `PATH`, e.g. `C:\python-qt5\PyQt5`.