# when i try convert file .ui to .py i got this error

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

when i try use pyuic5 to convert file at the first time

```
C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5>pyuic5 -x C:\Users\Egypt\Desktop\ftest.ui -o C:\Users\Egypt\Desktop\ftest.py
```

i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: That question has been answered many times, please do a search on the site and try the solutions they propose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt5 pyuic module error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381660/pyqt5-pyuic-module-error)